# FitNesse: Access the Test Results and other data in Java

Tags: java, json, fitnesse, suite

I have a suite created in FitNesse.

All the Test pages under that suite are created using Java.

When I run the suite, I am able to see the results in FitNesse.

Now I want to access the data, results, suite name, etc. in Java.

Also, I need to update HP-Quality Control (ALM) with the results.

Is there an API I can use to access the FitNesse results in Java or to update ALM directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the FitNesse Test Page or Test Suite results using Fitnesse RESTful services.

You can follow up [here](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices).

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience using alm, but assuming importing test results is a common use case: 
You can use fitnesse's junit runner to run suites. The name and results are then available as junit results. Is there a standard way to import those? I assume there is.

Comment: no need to do that.. I have found a the solution. you have to append &format=xml to the URL of the page or the suite and you will get the result in an XML. This is using fitnesse RESTful services.You can have more info here: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices